# Ckeditor auto add class to p

Tags: ckeditor

I would like to add class "text-justify" automatically to every p, anyone know how to do this?

Now I am using this code:

```
    CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    if (dialogName == 'table' || dialogName == 'tableProperties') {
        var info = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');

        // Remove fields
        var cellSpacing = info.remove('txtCellSpace');
        var cellPadding = info.remove('txtCellPad');
        var border = info.remove('txtBorder');
        var width = info.remove('txtWidth');
        var height = info.remove('txtHeight');
        var align = info.remove('cmbAlign');
    }
});

$('#content, #longContent').ckeditor({
    contentsCss: '/CMS/style_ckeditor.css',
    allowedContent: true,
    extraPlugins: 'button,menubutton,htmlbuttons,menu,floatpanel,panel',
    htmlbuttons: [
        {
            name:'button1',
            icon:'icon1.png',
            html:'<p class="act-left">Sekretarz Zgromaczenia<br /><strong>Alfred Błaszczyk</strong></p><p class="act-right">Przewodniczący Zgromadzenia<br /><strong>Tomasz Radomski</strong></p><div class="clearfix"></div>',
            title:'Dodaj podpisy'
        },
        {
            name:'button2',
            icon:'icon3.png',
            html:'<ol class="law"><li>&nbsp;<ol><li>tekst</li></ol></li></ol>',
            title:'Dodaj paragraf'
        }
    ]
}).ckeditorGet().on('insertElement', function (event) {
    var el = event.data;

    if (el.is('table')) {
        $(event.data.$)
            .addClass('table table-bordered table-striped')
            .removeAttr('cellpadding cellspacing')
            .wrap('<div class="table-responsive"></div>');
    }
}, null, null, 20);
```

It works for adding classes for table, but when I would like to do similar to P, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

just use :

```
$('#content').ckeditor({
    on: {
        instanceReady: function () {
            this.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules({
                elements: {
                    ul: function (el) {
                        el.addClass('ul');
                    },
                    table: function (el) {
                        el.addClass('entry');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

For Ckeditor4